# Laravel : File:delete don't delete the file

Tags: php, file, laravel

I have this function to delete image when the row is deleted

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $slider = Slider::find($id);
        $fileName = $slider->image;
        $fullPath = asset('/images/banner/' . $fileName);
        //dd($fullPath);
        File::delete($fullPath);
        $slider->delete();
        return Redirect::to('admin/home-slider');
    }
```

but sill returned without the file delete.
what I did wrong here?

**Update**
for other who may face the same problem 
in my case I deleted the `public` from my project before to clean my URL based on this [tutorial](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/)  
Solved by just removing the `asset` from the `$fullPath`
 and left it just like that `$fullPath = 'images/banner/' . $fileName;` 
and it's working just fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `base_path()` instead of asset

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $slider = Slider::find($id);
        $fileName = $slider->image;
        $fullPath = base_path().'/public/images/banner/'. $fileName;
        //dd($fullPath);
        File::delete($fullPath);
        $slider->delete();
        return Redirect::to('admin/home-slider');
    }
```

updated

you can add all images inside the public folder

[image]

Comment: my images folder exists in the root of my project, but `base_path()` will point to `/app`

Comment: no.base path will return root of directory of the project and app_path() will return app folder path and i believe you have images inside /public/images/banner/

Comment: yes you are right `app_path()` will return app folder path but the images directory not there it's on the root. see if I use `app_path()` I will get path like that `C:\wamp\www\gt\local/images/banner/0kaQfr_5.jpg` which is wrong path it should be something like this `C:\wamp\www\gt\images/banner/0kaQfr_5.jpg`

Comment: can you tell me your  project structure

Comment: @YousefAltaf.put your all images inside public folder of the laravel and you can create image folder inside public folder

Comment: @YousefAltaf. i have added image in my answer check it .you have to create images folder inside public folder

Comment: I deleted this folder once before, but dose this makes any different, I thought the `File::delete` only looks for the file path and delete it like the `unlink` correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @YousefAltaf.if you have created folder in root then try $fullPath = base_path().'/images/banner/'. $fileName;

Comment: File delete uses unlink

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: Hay thx you given me the key to the answer I just removed all path assists and it worked no `base_path()` nor `asset` and the good news it's working fine now :) thx brother

Comment: @YousefAltaf.Glade it helped you .so i have learnt somethink from this question